# Why we can't initial a public mapping in a struct?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, mapping, struct

```
contract MyContract {
    struct Balance {
        uint numDeposit;
        mapping(address=> uint) public Deposit; //It will give an error due the public keyword
        uint numWithdraw;
        mapping(address=> uint) Withdraw;
    }   
}
```

Why we can't create a getter function with **public** keyword for our mapping in a struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not allowed by the Solidity compiler to declare a public property inside struct. The auto-generated getter function cannot be created for a mapping inside a struct because struct itself doesn't have storage location. Each instance of the struct will have its own storage location, and so the compiler cannot generate a single getter function that will work for all instances of the struct.

you need to create your own custom getter function. For example

```
function getDeposit(address user) public view returns (uint) {
    return balances[user].Deposit;
}
```